# How pass object of array child to parent with Typescript in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I try to add new book details like title,descripton... I can set bookData with input values but i can't pass from child to parent.
This is my child comp. and i can see array with console.log in bookData

```
import { ChangeEvent, useState } from "react";
import { NewBook } from './BookType'
function NewBookModal() {
    const [title, settitle] = useState<string>("")
    const [url, seturl] = useState<string>("")
    const [description, setdescription] = useState<string>("")
    const [bookData, setBookData] = useState<NewBook[]>([])

    const changeValue = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        if (event.target.name === "title") {
            settitle(event.target.value)
        }
        if (event.target.name === "url") {
            seturl(event.target.value)
        }
        if (event.target.name === "description") {
            setdescription(event.target.value)
        }
    }
    const addNewBook = () => {
        debugger
        setBookData([
            ...bookData,
            { description: description, title: title, url: url, }
        ]);
        seturl("")
        settitle("")
        setdescription("")
return(...
```

these are interfaces

```
export interface IBook {
    url:string,
    description:string,
    title:string,
    image:string
}
export interface NewBook{
    url:string,
    description:string,
    title:string,
    image?:string,
}
```

and this is my parent comp.

```
import { IBook } from './BookType'
import BooklistItem from './BooklistItem'
import NewBookModal from './NewBook';
function Booklists() {
    const [books, setBooks] = useState<IBook[]>([]);
    const url = "https://localhost:7065/api/BookRecommendation"
    const getData = () => {
        fetch(url)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
                setBooks(res.data)
            })
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        getData()
    }, [books])
    return (
        <div>
            <NewBookModal/>
            <BooklistItem book={books} />
        </div>
    )

}
```

i did everythings that comes to my mind but didn't work

Comment: https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/sharing-state-between-components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your parent componenet `Booklists` you can create a function that takes a `NewBook` as paramater and add it to `books` :

```js
const addNewBook(book : NewBook) => {
  setBooks([...books,book])
}
```

Then pass this function to `<NewBookModal/>` as `props` so you can use it from the child componenet to add a new book to the state of the parent one :

```
<NewBookModal addbook={addNewBook}/>
```

and from `NewBookModal` :

```
function NewBookModal({addbook}) {
//...
addbook({ description: description, title: title, url: url})
}
```

But here the problem is that, in you parent component, you have declared your state this way :

```
const [books, setBooks] = useState<IBook[]>([]);
```

However it will recieve items of type `newBook` 
 I don't really see a reason for having this two types what I suggest is to have only one type `book` and use it everywhere:

```
export interface Book{
    url:string,
    description:string,
    title:string,
    image?:string,
}
```

You can always check with :

```
if(myBook.imgage) // here myBook is an instance of `Book`
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass setBooks from parent component

```
<NewBookModal setBooks={setBooks} />
```

In Child component while adding new book setBooks with previous state:

```
const addNewBook = () => {
setBooks((prevState) => {
  return [...prevState, { description, title, url }];
});
```

};